# How to resize the width of the JSpinner arrows?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jspinner

Is there a simple way to edit the width of the JSpinner arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setPreferredSize()` :

```
    Dimension d = spinner.getPreferredSize();  
    d.width = 50;  
    spinner.setPreferredSize(d);
```

Be careful with LayoutManager, which can modify this preferred size if it is out of bounds.

Comment: In general, it's [better](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) to rely on the UI delegate's preferred size.